# Why are my added items not showing in the listbox in C# windows form .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, button, windows-forms-designer

I'm designing this simple windows application that helps  to register students in courses
for a University.
Below is its design (GUI) [image]

Once the user clicks on Add button (only after typing in the Id in its text box and Name in its text box as well. The Student Id and Name must be shown in the listbox( listbox1). However; my code has no errors and no items are being displayed in lisbox1.

this is my code snippet for the Add Button :

```
if(txtId.Text.Trim() == String.Empty || txtName.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure to fill");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Trim());

            new Student(txtName.Text, id);
            

        }
         catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

And below is the code for the showStudents Method:

```
private void ShowStudents()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(student.ToArray());
    }
```

Note: I have done the class and I declared a list at the beginning of the form

```
 List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
```

Below is My Class's Code as well ( Class name is Students):

```
{
    private int StudentId;
    private string StudentName;

    public String studentName
    {
        get { return StudentName; }
        set { StudentName = value; }
    }

   public int studentId
    {
        get { return StudentId; }
        set { StudentId = value; }
    }

    public Student(string StudentName, int studentId)
    {
        this.StudentName = StudentName;
        this.StudentId = studentId;
    }

    public Student(int v1, string v2)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format( StudentId + "/t" + StudentName);
    }

    internal static void Add(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `new Student` you create.

Comment: @Crowcoder isnt the showStudents method what adds students? I have read list methods and Add Range adds the items and inside i added the items in student list . That's what I understood and tried to implement . Can you explain more, please?

Comment: When you are creating a new Student it is not added into the student List. You have to add the newly created student to the list. 
var stud = new Student(txtName.Text, id); 
student.Add(stud);

Comment: Tried that and still, they didn't show in the listbox

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing a critical addition:

```
//Add the content to the listBox list again
listBox1.Items.Add(stu);
```

Here are the complete steps:

Winform:

[image]

Winform Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace case2._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtId.Text.Trim() == String.Empty || txtName.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Make sure to fill");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Trim());
                //Create a new student to receive the input ID and Name
                var stu = new Student(txtName.Text, id);
                //Add the content to the listBox list again
                listBox1.Items.Add(stu);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Student
    {
        private int StudentId;
        private string StudentName;

        public String studentName
        {
            get { return StudentName; }
            set { StudentName = value; }
        }

        public int studentId
        {
            get { return StudentId; }
            set { StudentId = value; }
        }

        public Student(string StudentName, int studentId)
        {
            this.StudentName = StudentName;
            this.StudentId = studentId;
        }

        public Student(int v1, string v2)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(StudentId + "\t" + StudentName);
        }

        internal static void Add(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: thank you, I also have a question whats the difference between Add and AddRange. I was working on another project and somehow items only show in the AddRange method not the Add

Comment: @annonymus22 You can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.addrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_ObjectCollection_AddRange_System_Object___), they The added objects are not the same. Addrange is relative to range addition. For details, you can open a new case for discussion. If this case has been resolved, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.